# Google cloud vision DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION language hints не работают корректно для русского языка

Tags: c#, .net, распознавание-символов, google-cloud

Работаю с распознаванием текста на документах. Библиотека для .NET Core

```
var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
                ImageContext context = new ImageContext();
                foreach (var hints in context.LanguageHints)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("hint " + hints);
                }
               var response = client.DetectDocumentText(fromBytes, context);
```

На русском языке есть фраза "Однажды вечером"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я скармливаю этот документ Google DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION без явного указания языка, тогда получаю результат "ОДНАЖДЫ BELEPOM"

Окей, возможно он сомневается в языке, укажем явно, что это русский

```
  context.LanguageHints.Add("ru");
  var response = client.DetectDocumentText(fromBytes, context);
```

Результат прежний - второе слово целиком латиницей.

Думаю, как то не так задаю подсказку? Попробуем для примера другие языки

```
context.LanguageHints.Add("en");
  var response = client.DetectDocumentText(fromBytes, context);
```

Результат

```
DAHAYKALI BELEPOM
```

Т.е. сам функционал подсказок работает, просто видимо русское слово "ВЕЧЕРОМ" распознается с такой низкой достоверностью, что он делает fallback на английский язык.

Вопрос - как вообще запретить ему распознавать слово "Вечером", да и вообще текущий текст, с учётом английского языка? Пусть хоть как пытается русские буквы распознать, пусть и с меньшей достоверностью.

Comment: Можно просто выпилить слова, содержащие латиницу. `string text = "ОДНАЖДЫ BELEPOM"; char[] latin = Enumerable.Range('A', 26).Select(c => (char)c).ToArray(); string[] words = text.Split().Where(s => !latin.Any(c => s.Contains(c))); text = string.Join(" ", words);` А вообще, есть движок распознавания текста `Tesseract`, поизучайте, и гугл не понадобится.

Comment: @aepot Так слова то мне возвращает гугл, смысл в том что я выпилю латиницу? У меня просто не будет некоторых слов, которые он подумал что на латинице

Comment: Может `"ru-RU"`?

Comment: @Bulson Нет, у них `ru` - https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages